# SQL insert , update stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE `db_customer`.`customer` (
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` DATE NOT NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `short_biography` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `photo` BLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
);
```

DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `table_in` (
      first_name VARCHAR(45),
      lastname VARCHAR(45),
      date_of_birth DATE,
      country VARCHAR(45),
      email VARCHAR(100),
      username VARCHAR(45),
      short_biography TEXT
    )
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO customer (
        first_name,
        last_name,
        date_of_birth,
        country,
        email,
        username,
        short_biography
      ) VALUES (
        customer_id,
        first_name,
        laast_name,
        date_of_birth,
        country,
        email,
        username,
        short_biography
    );
    END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Hi. What error do you get?

Comment: I get syntax error, i dont't now is this a wright way to write a code , a am totaly beginner with SQL

Comment: 1) [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) is the reserved keyword, don't use it for the SP name. 2) `customer_id` is the auto increment, no need to pass and insert the value.

Comment: ok, i will change, txs, but what is wrong with rest of code?

Comment: Are you getting error for the `;`, if so try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158299/2451726)

Comment: i cahnged @Arulkumar , is that ok now, txs?

Comment: `DELIMITER $$` is your friend. You have to explain MySQL that it should not interpret all the `;`-separated instructions within your stored procedure, instead it should treat it as a whole block.

Comment: Where do columns first_name and laast_name come from in your insert?  Think they are called something different in your create.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `table_in` 
(customer_id, first_name VARCHAR(45), lastname VARCHAR(45), date_of_birth DATE,
country VARCHAR(45), email VARCHAR(100), username VARCHAR(45), short_biography TEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer (first_name, laast_name, date_of_birth, country, email, username, short_biography) VALUES (customer_id, first_name, laast_name, date_of_birth, country, email, username, short_biography);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then it will compile. Otherwise MySQL will interpret your stored procedure instruction-by-instruction.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your column names are not matching with the columns used inside the SP (`first_name`, `laast_name`).

2)  `customer_id` is the auto increment, so no need use inside the insert block.

3) As suggested in this [answer](/a/19158374/) use the `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `table_in` 
(first_name VARCHAR(45), lastname VARCHAR(45), date_of_birth DATE,
country VARCHAR(45), email VARCHAR(100), username VARCHAR(45), short_biography TEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer (`name`, lastname, date_of_birth, country, email, username, short_biography) 
    VALUES (first_name, lastname, date_of_birth, country, email, username, short_biography);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: TXS a lot to everyone, everythyng is ok.